# android: I used dlib to get facial landlandmarks in real-time, Want help in increasing speed when face landmarks detection

Tags: android, dlib

After face detected, it takes 100ms to get facial landmarks. FPS is about 6，`full_object_detection shape = sp(img, det);` this codes costs 100ms, how can I increase speed in face landmarkes detection?

Answer (score 1):

Even I had the same problem initially.

I suggest you do 2 things :

1. Resize the frame for detection task(ex: 1280*960 frame to 320*240 resolution)
   You can make use of opencv method :

   `#define FACE_DOWNSAMPLE_RATIO 4`

   `cv::resize(image, image_small, cv::Size(), 1.0/FACE_DOWNSAMPLE_RATIO, 1.0/FACE_DOWNSAMPLE_RATIO);`
2. Skip the frames in detection process :

   `#define SKIP_FRAMES 4`

   `static int counts=0;`

   `if ( counts % SKIP_FRAMES == 0 ) {`

   `faces = detector(cimg_small);`

   `}`

   cimg_small is image of dlib type:(pixel_traits: bgr_pixel)

   Refer this link : [Here](http://www.learnopencv.com/speeding-up-dlib-facial-landmark-detector/). If you do these two process in your native method you will get 13-17 fps. If you still want to raise the rate of FPS/detection should be faster you can do detection in specific ROI like MSQRD App. Further, if there are any other techniques please do suggest. It will help me too. Thank you. Good luck.